# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, build.gradle

The code worked fine on windows. I am trying to run my android app on the latest m1 chip MacBook air. I didn't enable Rosetta. I am using android studio 2020.3.1 patch3 with arm 64 preview. Below is my build.Gradle files and my error. Could anyone tell me how to fix this? thank you so much.     \

### Module Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
androidExtensions{
    experimental = true
}
android {
    compileSdk 23

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kotlinmessenger"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    // Declare the dependency for the Cloud Storage library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    // Declare the dependency for the Realtime Database library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'org.chromium.net:cronet-embedded:76.3809.111'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0")

    implementation ('com.xwray:groupie:2.0.3')

    implementation('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8')

    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

### Project Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### My error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.2.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/zjendex/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/01e9c09422b2e40de45818786ea0eeb9/transformed/appcompat-1.2.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.3-7396180-osx Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed....

Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable
```